# How can I get a correct string split by coma on Java?

Tags: java, string, split

I have the next csv file:

```
hotel,is_canceled,lead_time, ..
Resort Hotel,0,300, ..
Resort Hotel,0,
```

And the problem comes when, for example, i want an ArrayList with the first column:

```
[Resort Hotel, Resort Hotel, .. ]
```

To do that i read the file row by row, on each row (it's an entire string row) i use row.split(","). But the result i get from doing that is like this:
`[Resort, Hotel, Resort, Hotel, ...]` when i want `[Resort Hotel, Resort Hotel, ...]`
I've tried using split("\,") and split(Pattern.quote(",")) but none of those work. Dont know why it splits the data also when there's a space, not only with coma.

Any idea?
I'll put here the code in case it's an error on my code. What i do first is use a Scanner to read the file, then (on the first while) i search for a concrete attribute (in this case hotel) and on the second while i get row by row splitting the row in comas and grabbing the one attribute i want, adding it to the result Array.

```
public String[] read_column_scan(String file, String atribut) {
    File _file = new File(file);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(_file);
        String data;
        data = inputStream.next();
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        boolean found = false;
        int i = -1;
        while(!found && (i < values.length)) {
            ++i;
            if(values[i].equals(atribut)) found = true;
        }
        ArrayList<String> result_aux = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] values2;
        while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
            data = inputStream.next();
            values2 = data.split(",");
            String aux = values2[i];
            result_aux.add(aux);
        }
        String[] result = new String[result_aux.size()];
        result_aux.toArray(result);
        return result;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should use a CSV parser instead of splitting the `String`. Having said that, `String#split()` works just fine, the issue is with your `Scanner` which returns word by word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) in class `Scanner` reads the next token and the default delimiter for a token is whitespace. You want the `Scanner` to read an entire line of the CSV file. Hence you require method `hasNextLIne()` to see if there is another line in the file, and method `nextLine()` to read an entire line. Then your `split(",")` will work because your string is an entire line and not just a word.

```java
public String[] read_column_scan(String file, String atribut) {
    File _file = new File(file);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(_file);
        String data;
        data = inputStream.nextLine(); // change here
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        boolean found = false;
        int i = -1;
        while(!found && (i < values.length)) {
            ++i;
            if(values[i].equals(atribut)) found = true;
        }
        ArrayList<String> result_aux = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] values2;
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) { // change here
            data = inputStream.nextLine(); // change here
            values2 = data.split(",");
            String aux = values2[i];
            result_aux.add(aux);
        }
        String[] result = new String[result_aux.size()];
        result_aux.toArray(result);
        return result;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was asking for! Thanks a lot! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You will save yourself alot of pain if you use a CSV parser library instead of trying to parse it yourself. You are already missing the proper handling of quoted values.

I recommend using OpenCSV http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#even_quicker_start

Comment: Before using Scanner i already tried OpenCSV but got an error message at the initialization: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils at com.opencsv.CSVParser.<init>(CSVParser.java:99) at com.opencsv.CSVReader.<init>(CSVReader.java:97) and the way im initializting is like this: FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file); CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader); ... Is anything wrong with that initialization? i tried soo much things with OpenCSV.. And thanks for the fast response!

Comment: It sounds like an issue with your build that resulted in you not loading transitive dependencies. From that error message you can tell that openCSV has a dependency on apache commons 3 which was probably not included in your classpath.

Comment: Hmm...seems like that's happening. But how do i add the opencsv library correctly? I downloaded the opencsv.jar, put it on my project (im using IntellyJ), added this opencsv.jar as a module and that's all...maybe im losing something?

Comment: Okay nevermind, the problem was that i needed a Java commons library, the java-lang3.1...Everything works perfect now. Thanks!